# Android Studio Gradle Peer not authenticated

Tags: android-studio, gradle

With Android Studio 1.2.2, I am unable to build with gradle with the following message:
    Error:A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
>   Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':CordovaLib:classpath'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+.
>           Required by:
>               android:CordovaLib:unspecified
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0+.
>   Failed to list versions for com.android.tools.build:gradle.
>   Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
>   Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
>   peer not authenticated

I tried downloading gradle 2.4 and setting the gradle distribution locally, but still did not help.

Also, making the following change in the build file did not work.

```
jcenter {
        url "http://jcenter.bintray.com/"
    }
```

How can this be resolved?